# Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral in Banach spaces

Tags: integration, analysis, reference-request

Is there a generalization of the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral to the case of operator-valued integrands and integrators? If so, I would be happy about any reference.

I only was able to find books about the *Riemann*-Stieltjes integral in Banach spaces. See for example, chapter 2 of [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255588190_A_Fredholm-type_theorem_for_linear_integral_equations_of_Stieltjes_type).

Comment: I think you're looking for the Bochner integral. A good reference is probably Vector Measures by Diestel & Uhl.

Comment: @Demophilus No, I'm looking for a generalization of the Riemann-Lebesgue integral in Banach spaces which is described in chapter 2 of [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255588190_A_Fredholm-type_theorem_for_linear_integral_equations_of_Stieltjes_type).

Comment: I think @Demophilus' comment is accurate: vector-valued integrals of various sorts exist. From the side of imitating Riemann or Lebesgue integrals, there's Bochner's construction and generalizations to integrands with values in quasi-complete (and locally convex) TVS's. From the other side, _characterizing_ integrals without a construction, there is the Gelfand-Pettis or "weak" integral (which is a deceptive name, since the weakness is in the _hypotheses_, not the conclusion). An example-discussion is in http://www.math.umn.edu/ ̃garrett/m/fun/notes 2016-17/vector-valued integrals.pdf

Comment: @paulgarrett My [other question on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285093/lebesgue-stieltjes-type-integral-in-the-it%C5%8D-isometry) is the motivation behind this question here. Maybe you could take a look such that you better understand what I'm after. (BTW, there seems to be some typo in your link.)

Comment: The link should be http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/notes_2016-17/vector-valued_integrals.pdf  Dunno what happened to it.

Comment: @paulgarrett Thanks for reposting it. Did you take a look at the other question?